# php array_diff not working with collection of value objects

Tags: php

```
        var_dump($this->externalProjects);
        var_dump($this->projects);
        $result = array_diff($this->externalProjects, $this->projects);
        print_r($result);
```

It outputting:

```
array (size=6) // external projects
  0 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[79]
      private 'name' => string '(A11) Tyre Pyrolysis Plant, Civil, Mech & Elec' (length=46)
  1 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[80]
      private 'name' => string '(B) - Millerhill New Depot Proposal' (length=35)
  2 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[81]
      private 'name' => string '(B13) Port of Tyne Wood Pellet Handling Facilities' (length=50)
  3 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[82]
      private 'name' => string '(C) - Millerhill Proposed New Depot' (length=35)
  4 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[83]
      private 'name' => string '(S) - EGIP New Depot Proposal' (length=29)
  5 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[85]
      private 'name' => string '00352 Allerton - Building fabric & structure survey' (length=51)
array (size=1) //projects
  0 => 
    object(CloseCall\ValueObject\Project)[15]
      private 'name' => string '(A11) Tyre Pyrolysis Plant, Civil, Mech & Elec' (length=46)

// no output for array_diff
```

Comment: Try `array_diff_assoc()`

Comment: Still no luck @aldrin27

Comment: Infact, I don't want to be comparing the keys - I thought that might be the issue with array_diff in the first place, but apparently not. I'm not sure array_diff is capable of comparing objects.

Comment: Really not sure what the reason for the downvote is at all.

Comment: Maybe your array doesn't have difference so it has no output. And I don't downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Compare objects like this, you should be looking at `array_udiff`. The main difference between the two functions is that `array_udiff` takes a callback function as a parameter which is then used to compare the objects.

Please see the Docs. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php

**Example**

```
int comparison(Array $a, Array $b){
    if ($a['id']==$b['id'] && $a['other']==$b['other'] && $a['timestamp']==$b['timestamp']){
        return 0
    }else{
        return -1
    }
}    

array_udiff($a, $b, 'comparison')
```

This function checks to see if each of the array key values are the same, and if so returns 0 which `array_udiff` would then remove that object from the comparing arrays.